# Execute Python commands on a server via a GET request

Tags: python

On My server, i have installed spleeter which is a python app. I am able to successfully call the spleeter commands in my terminal to execute my required commands.

I want to be able to execute those terminal commands with an http get request.

Basically, i have an android app thats supposed to make a Get request to my vps server which executes the spleeter commands and returns the response.

Please how can i create the Get endpoint. I need pointer please.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the most simplistic sense, you can create a python web app (using Django, Flask or raw Python, etc.) that serves an HTTP endpoint. In that web app, you can do something like this that will run commands inside a python function, depending on the contents of the GET request:

```
   import os

   def run_command(command):
      if command = "ls":
         os.system('ls -l')
   ...
```

The only problem here is that, without authentication, this is horribly insecure. Anyone with access to the internet could call your endpoint and run those commands, unless you add some sort of authentication into your Android and/or Python app to validate requests.

Even passing a simple "token" in a custom HTTP header from the app to the web server might be better than nothing to verify it is a legit user sending the command.

The other problem here is that the Python (or web server) user has to have permissions to run the command, that is another security issue altogether.

Alternatively, you could have the endpoint store the commands it received via GET requests into a Redis queue or something, and then have a separate script running locally validate the commands and run them on the system so at least you separate the web portion from the server user portion.

Without more details, it is hard to know exactly what you want to accomplish.

Reference: https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/